# Выборка, удовлетворяющая фильтру

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица

```
id  element_id  value      property
1       1       красный    цвет
2       2       зеленый    цвет
3       3       желтый     цвет
4       4       красный    цвет
5       1       50         цена
6       2       70         цена
7       3       100        цена
```

Необходимо выбрать `element_id`, который бы удовлетворял фильтру, например, при запросе "цвет - красный, цена = 50" должно вернутся "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select th1.elem_id from table as th1 inner join table as th2 on th2.elem_id=th1.emem_id where th1.value='красный' and th1.property='цвет' and th2.value='50 деревянных' and th2.property='цена'
```

саму на себя джойнить нужно согласно вашей структуре таблицы. Вообще, она (структура) ужасна. хранить цвет и стоимость в одном поле = караул

Comment: битрикс... цена это первое что в голову пришло, что ж вы все за нее цепляетесь ) можно было написать к примеру размер, артикул, бренд, сути задачи это не меняет.

Comment: @FLK, Ваш проект обречен на провал.

Comment: проект так то уже давно работает, используя стандартные методы битрикса, но захотелось немножко оптимизировать, но как видно ничего разумней этого очевидного ответа никому на ум не приходит.

Comment: тут и не может ничего разумнее прийти. по вашей структуре - только джойнить саму на себя.

Comment: всегда есть наивное "а вдруг?" )

Comment: ``th2.value='50 деревянных'`` - вот это вы как придумали? человек просил меньше 60. А, вы наверное в таблицу посмотрели... )

Comment: главное идея понятна ) исправил в вопросе )

Comment: добавил ответ. идея у вас получается такая, что если условие не четкое (а в фильтрах по цене только такие и бывают), то такой запрос не годится.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    p.element_id
    from Props p
    where
        (p.property = 'цвет' and p.value = 'красный')
        or (p.property = 'цена' and p.value = '50')
    group by p.element_id
    having COUNT(p.element_id) > 1
```

без джойнов:)

Comment: интересное решение, сначала не дочитав до конца решил, что не сработает... всё равно что то меня в нем смущает, пока еще не понял что именно. но плюсую )

Comment: преимущество моего способа может быть в том, что если фильтр идет по десяти и более парам типа "параметер" = "значение", то в динамических запросах с джойнами придется делать десять джойнов, что может сказаться негативно на производительности, а в моем увеличится только секция where, т.е масштабируемо касательно сложности фильтра))

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать две таблицы.

> **color**

```
id    |    value
 1    |   красный
 2    |   зеленый
 3    |   желтый
 4    |   красный
```

> **pr**

```
id    |  cid    |  price
 5    |   1     |   50
 6    |   2     |   70
 7    |   3     |   100
```

> **cid** — color id

И запрос:

```
select * 
from `color` 
  left join `pr` 
   on `color`.`id` = `pr`.`cid` 
where `pr`.`price` < 60 and `color`.`value` = 'красный'
```

Comment: Наконец-то. Ибо вот нормальный подход к решению проблемы. Плюс все равно поставлю

Comment: @LordySL @exec с удовольствием понаблюдаю как вы будете менять структуру бд в битриксе...

Comment: @FLK мы не используем такое. Да и наверняка подобное можно осуществить на битриксе. А еще не понятно зачем задавать вопрос левой учетной записи а не с основного аккаунта?)

Comment: @FLK у меня свой движок, который я как хочу, так и изменяю.

Comment: @exec хотел бы и я писать только на своем движке (

Comment: @FLK в чем проблема? [**Вот тут**][1] описан мой движок, берите его и пишите.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/90154#90410

Comment: @LordySL давно здесь не был а вспоминать на какое мыло регался дольше чем создать новый акк

Comment: @exec я не пишу на нем не потому что его нет ) а потому что клиентам нужен битрикс с его сертификатами ) джумла, потому что индусы задешего смогут подправить если что и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```
select el.id, el.name, pr1.v price, pr2.v color
from elements el
join prop pr1 on el.id = pr1.element_id and pr1.property = "price" and pr1.v <60
join prop pr2 on el.id = pr2.element_id and pr2.property = "color" and pr2.v = "red"
```

elements - таблица элементов, с ней джойнить гораздо проще и логичнее.
Таким образом получаем фактически таблицу товаров со значениями свойств, по которым фильтруем.

Корректно так же создать view для такого запроса по товарам со всеми возможными свойствами, и фильтровать его...

ЗЫ битрикс - это АД.

Comment: спасибо, отличный ответ, действительно узко я мыслил.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так если не ошибаюсь)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT element_id  FROM название таблицы WHERE value="красный"  ",$db)
            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            do
            {

           echo ($myrow['element_id']);
            }
            while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: в вашем случае вернет вернет два элемента один из которых, а именно равный "4" не удовлетворяет условию фильтра так как не имеет цены

Comment: Так надо писать чтоб с 2 условиями)

Comment: ну дак о чем собственно и вопрос ) можно сделать два запроса, получить два массива и оставить только элементы существующие в обоих, но хотелось бы получить более элегантное решение.

Comment: то что цена указана с буквами несущественно там может быть что угодно. есть таблица с элементами, у каждого элемента есть свойства, "цвет" и "цена", значение этих свойств и хранятся в приведенной выше таблице. нужно узнать какие элементы удовлетворяют заданному фильтру.

Comment: Хах так все равно будет вылезать элемент "4". Если нужно сделать выборку по 2 условиям, то просто создайте 2 столбца. 1 с ценой, второй с цветом. И причем тут вообще массивы. Просто итоговая цель не ясна.

Comment: @FLK 
у каждого элемента есть свойства, "цвет" и "цена"
Я что то не вижу! В столбце value либо цвет указан либо цена. Цену указывать с буквами идиотизм. Так как выводиться значение будет как текст. А вам необходимо вывести где цена меньше 60. То есть по вашему машина поймет 50 р.< 60 ?

Comment: да машина это отлично поймет, ибо строки тоже сравниваются прекрасно, но суть вопроса не в этом, сейчас уберу чтобы не путать пытливые умы ) изменить структуру таблицы никак нельзя.

Comment: Щито? При чем тут сравнение? И как это число с текстом сравнивать?

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `element_id`  FROM `table` WHERE `value`='красный' union SELECT `element_id`  FROM `table` WHERE `value`   < '60'") or die (mysql_error());
echo mysql_result($sql, 0); // 1
```

Comment: @johniek_comp у вас 1 столбец принимает сразу 2 значения?

Comment: я так понимаю результат выполнения запроса никто не проверял.

Comment: @FLK где проверять?

Comment: хотябы даже в говоле прокрутить, нужного результата, даже исправленный вариант не выдаст, к примеру будет вместо цвета свойство вес(кг) и элементы с весом в 60.